# Переключатель языка на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование

Имеется продублированная английская версия сайта. Сайт написан на php. Русская версия лежит в корне, английская версия лежит в папке /en. В куке language хранится используемый язык. Хочу написать скрипт, который бы автоматически подтягивал нужный php файл английской или русской версии в зависимости от этой куки. Кука меняется с помощью js при клике на переключатель.
А так же хотелось бы чтобы при обращении к главной странице английской версии url был просто

> site.com/en/

Сейчас при обращении по такому урлу, сайт редиректит на главную страницу в корне (т.е русскую версию), сейчас к главной странице английской версии можно обратится только как

> site.com/en/index

Comment: а какие функциональные и технические требования?

Answer (score 4):

Многие фреймворки имеют поддержку локализации. В наивном варианте можно сделать структуру, хранящую перевод каждой фразы в каждом языке.

```
$messages["ru"]["msg.button"] = "Кнопка";
...
$messages["en"]["msg.button"] = "Button";
...
```

Получение языка можно сделать через параметр:

```
$lang = $_GET["lang"];
```

Тогда вывод фразы будет таким:

```
<button><?php echo $messages[$lang]["msg.button"]; ?></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый быстрый способ = Создаешь 2 папки (для 2х языков)

`1 - /en` 
 `2 - /ru`

Переводишь сайт на 2 языка , и вставляешь каждый в нужную папку с языком.
Делаешь значник с ссылками на разные версии языка

```
<a href="/en/" hreflang="en">
<a href="/ru/" hreflang="ru">
```

Получается 2 экземпляра сайта , с 2-мя разными языками.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень и очень просто на самом деле.
Создаешь файлы с идентификатором нужного языка, где содержатся массивы с переводами фраз. Примерно, так:
Файл "ru.lang": 
$lang = array(

'save' => 'Сохранить',
'true' => 'Правда'

/* И т.д. */

);

Файл "en.lang": 
$lang = array(

'save' => 'Save',
'true' => 'True'

/* etc */

);

Дальше создаешь скриптик который при получении, например $_GET['lang'] проверял lang файл и если он существует, то записывал (setcookie('language', $_GET['lang'], ...)) сессию с нужным идентификатором.

Пишу на коленке, но это действительно все просто реализовать. Не забудь только кукушку language проверять на наличие. Если существует, то подключать нужный файл, с нужным идентификатором.